# Bring to the front the MainWindow in Pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qmainwindow

I am dealing with the following problem, while I am having multiple windows open, i would like to build a function linked to a button to bring to the front the Main window.

Thank you in advance.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
                              QLabel)

class Window2(QMainWindow):                           # <===
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Window 2")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Back to window1", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.window1) 


    def window1(self):                                             # <===
        pass;


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "First Window"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500

        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Go to window 2 ", self)
        self.pushButton.move(275, 200)
            
        self.label = QLabel("window 1", self)
        self.label.move(285, 175)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.window2)              # <===



    def window2(self):                                             # <===
        self.w = Window2()
        self.w.show()
        
        


def main(): 
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =  Window()

    window.show()
    #app.exec_()
    exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Regards

I am expecting a function to call back the widget "Window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could emit a signal from your second window that your fist window listens for, and calls `.raise_()` when triggered.

Update:  Added a call to `activateWindow` in the first windows callback. thanks @musicmante

For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal  # import signal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
                              QLabel)

class Window2(QMainWindow):

    unfocus = pyqtSignal()   # create signal

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Window 2")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Back to window1", self)
        # button press emits signal
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.unfocus.emit) 


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "First Window"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Go to window 2 ", self)
        self.pushButton.move(275, 200)
        self.label = QLabel("window 1", self)
        self.label.move(285, 175)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.window2)              # <===

    def window2(self):                                             # <===
        self.w = Window2()
        self.w.unfocus.connect(self.bring_to_top)  # listen for signal and raise_ to top focus
        self.w.show()

    def bring_to_top(self):
        self.activateWindow()
        self.raise_()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =  Window()
    window.show()
    #app.exec_()
    exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note that `raise()` only puts the widget on top of the "Qt parent". To Qt, the "main window" is not a parent, so it probably won't do nothing depending on the system (it doesn't work on Linux). Also, raising doesn't change the focus if the window is not actually "risen" due to the above. The proper way is to call [`activateWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow) and *then* eventually call `raise()` (as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise)). Also, the window *must* be visible, otherwise none of the above will have any effect.